# Let $F=\cos(y^{2}+z^{2})i+\sin(z^{2}+x^{2})j+e^{x^{2}+y^{2}}k$ be a vectore field on $\mathbb R^{3}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

Let $F=\cos(y^{2}+z^{2})i+\sin(z^{2}+x^{2})j+e^{x^{2}+y^{2}}k$ be a vectore field on $\mathbb R^{3}$. Calculate $\int_{S}F.ds$, where the surface $S$ is defined by $x^{2}+y^{2}=e^{z}\cos z~$, $~~0\leq z \leq \pi/2$ and oriented upward.

Is my solution is correct?
[image]

Comment: Write it up in an organized format instead of a mass of scattered calculations, and then we can see. Personally, I suspect you made two sign errors that just happened to cancel each other out. But because of the disorganization, I can't tell if this is the case or if you did spot the sign changes and cancelled them without noting it on your page. Why I say this is that $\int_V \nabla \cdot F\,dV = \int_{S_1}F\cdot\, ds + \int_{S_2} F\cdot\,ds$ is only true when $S_1, S_2$ are both outwardly oriented.

Answer (score 1):

Your sketch of the surface is not right, by the way. Since $\frac d{dz}(e^z\cos z) = e^z(\cos z-\sin z)$, the surface gets fatter until $z=\pi/4$, and then thinner all the way to a point at $z=\pi/2$. "Oriented upward" is probably not a good phrase. However, when you glue on the bottom disk, its outward-pointing normal needs to be $(0,0,-1)$. When you take the negative of this flux integral, you get the flux with the upward-pointing normal $(0,0,1)$, which you did compute. (There's no need to compute a cross-product here!!) As @PaulSinclair pointed out, your solution has cancelling negative signs but comes out correct.